# Why Unpack function returns array with starting index 1 in PHP

Tags: php

Why unpack() function in PHP returns an array of binary data  starting with the array index 1.

```
$str = "PHP";
$binary_data = unpack("C*",$str);
print_r($binary_data);
```

The above PHP scripts prints as below:

Array ( [1] => 80 [2] => 72 [3] => 80 )

Comment: not sure why, but you could run array_values to re-index the keys if it is really a problem

Comment: Your code is trying to convert a string to binary data, hence you have to use `pack`, not `unpack`

Comment: I tried with this($str = "0x123";) binary data, this also returns with array index 1.

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky Unpacking the string `"PHP"` is a legitimate test of `unpack()`. There's no reason to believe the OP meant to pack rather than unpack.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The array is an associative array with named keys, not a regular array with numeric keys. The idea is that you will name each format code and the result array will use those names as the array keys.

For example:

```
<?php
$str = "PHP";
$binary_data = unpack("C*letter",$str);
print_r($binary_data);
```

Result:

```
Array
(
    [letter1] => 80
    [letter2] => 72
    [letter3] => 80
)
```

From the [PHP manual](http://php.net/unpack):

> The unpacked data is stored in an associative array. To accomplish this you have to name the different format codes and separate them by a slash `/`. If a repeater argument is present, then each of the array keys will have a sequence number behind the given name.
>
> #### Example #1 unpack() example
>
> ```
> <?php
> $binarydata = "\x04\x00\xa0\x00";
> $array = unpack("cchars/nint", $binarydata);
> ?>
> ```
>
> The resulting array will contain the entries "chars" with value 4 and "int" with 160.
>
> #### Example #2 unpack() example with a repeater
>
> ```
> <?php
> $binarydata = "\x04\x00\xa0\x00";
> $array = unpack("c2chars/nint", $binarydata);
> ?>
> ```
>
> The resulting array will contain the entries "chars1", "chars2" and "int".

Comment: This doesn't really answer why it starts from 1 instead of 0 (`chars1` instead of `chars0` etc in the provided example). Also all arrays in php are technically associative.